# Why does send_keys keep hitting enter at the end?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

```
    eleUserMessage = driver.find_element_by_id("xxxxxxx")
    eleUserMessage.send_keys(email)
```

Im trying to use selenium with python to auto fill out a form and fill in my details. So far I have read in my info from a .txt file and stored them in variables for easy reference. When I Find the element and try to fill it out with send_keys, after each send_keys line, the form highlights the other fields that aren't filled in and says I need to fill them in before I submit. My code to submit the info is way after this code segment.

Why does send_keys try to submit the form or even send the enter key when I didn't tell it to? and how do I stop this from happening?

The main issue that this is causing is that the element ids change when they are highlighted in red since they are required fields. I need to get around that somehow. Please let me know what I can do.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with java. Please remove the java tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are storing your details in a text file, it is likely that when you create the email variable there is a newline at the end of the string as this is how text files work. This would explain why the form gets submitted because it is the equivalent of typing the email followed by the enter key. You can try to fix this by using

```py
eleUserMessage.send_keys(email.rstrip())
```

rstrip() is a builtin function and it by default, with no parameters, strips the whitespace and newlines from the right side.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to fill out a form ,then submit the finished form.
you can try :

```
    eleUserMessage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='name']")
    all_options = eleUserMessage.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
    for option in all_options:
        print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
        option.click()
        eleUserMessage.send_keys(email)
```